# Fragment visible behind last fragment and goes on

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Having Navigation drawer in Activity and changing Fragments by these lines of code

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
case R.id.home:
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ranking") == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.list_view_container, new HomeFragment(),
                        "ranking")
                .addToBackStack("ranking")
                .setTransition(
                        FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("ranking", 0);
    }
    return true;
case R.id.current_event:
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ranking1") == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.list_view_container, new CurrentEvents(),
                        "ranking1")
                .addToBackStack("ranking1")
                .setTransition(
                        FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("ranking1", 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I wanted Fragment to remain in memory so that it should not rebuilt again and again and fetch data from internet again and again so I have put the above method to get that but now, when I am changing the fragment by navigation drawer one fragment is replacing another and goes on and also I have to press back button=number of times new fragment created to exit from application. I want fragment in Backstack but not like this which is replacing one another. I want just one method at time. please help

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `add()`, the previous `Fragment` will not be removed from the container.

You should replace the calls to `add()` with `replace()`. For example, `case R.id.home` would become:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.list_view_container, new HomeFragment(),
            "ranking")
    .addToBackStack("ranking")
    .setTransition(
            FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .commit();
```

> I wanted Fragment to remain in memory so that it should not rebuilt again and again and fetch data from internet again and again

You could try `Fragment`'s `setRetainInstance(true)` to do that but it's not recommended (and I've never used it).

The other way which is more appropriate is to use `Fragment`'s `onSaveInstanceState()`. You can read about it at [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Answer (score 0):

> You can Check This Scenario, Hopefully it solve your Problem:-
>
> Try to Attach and Detach the Fragment from FragmentTransaction. When
>   you Move to Next Fragment detach the last one Fragment From
>   FragmentTransaction and when you wants to use it again then attach it.
>
> See sample code for how to Detach and Attach the Fragment, It will
>   help you :

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
                AndroidFragment androidFragment = (AndroidFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("android");
                AppleFragment appleFragment = (AppleFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("apple");
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                /** Detaches the androidfragment if exists */
                if(androidFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(androidFragment);

                /** Detaches the applefragment if exists */
                if(appleFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(appleFragment);

                /** If current tab is android */
                if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("android")){

                    if(androidFragment==null){
                        /** Create AndroidFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AndroidFragment(), "android");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(androidFragment);
                    }

                }else{    /** If current tab is apple */
                    if(appleFragment==null){
                        /** Create AppleFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new AppleFragment(), "apple");
                     }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(appleFragment);
                    }
                }
                ft.commit();

 `For Reference see this onTabChanged :` [http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/][1]
```